# Variables inside a Parallel.For

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

So I have 3 nested for loops with the inner two doing little work. I want to convert the outer-most loop into a parallel one.

My question is:

If I have a variable inside the loop, something that is used as a temp value holder and takes a new value each loop. Do I need to worry about that variable when the parallelism begins ?

I mean are all the threads gonna be over-writing the same variable ?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < persons.number; i++) //Loop all the people
    var Dates = persons[i].Appointments.bydate(DateStep);
```

Do I need to worry about the Dates variable in the parallel loop ?

Sorry for the bad formatting of my question but it's only my second question and I'm getting there.

Comment: Not `Var`, it is `var`. C# is a case sensitive language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short: No.

Because this variable is scoped inside the loop, it will be reassigned for every iteration of the loop anyways. It is not a value which is shared among different threads.

The only variables which you should worry about are those scoped outside of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer that was helpful ! but I kind of have a new question now.
These iterations are filling up a 2D array cells according to their findings. I know that the iterations will be filling specific cells of the array and they will not write on other threads` cells. Do I need to watch for concurrency and implement a locking mechanism ? like a Semaphore or a Mutex ? Or can I just leave it since I know that there will be no concurrency problems ?

Comment: If it is really an `Array` and not some other collection, and you can guarantee that no two threads will try to access the same cell, you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

`Dates` will be local to each loop iteration, so each thread will have a private copy on its own stack. No interference.

Be careful about variables declared outside the loop though.